# Transaction Management time out issue

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to run a query from our application through springs 2.5 and hibernate 3,But query is neither timed out nor returning results (query hangs out),When I run the same query from the query browser it is working fine.

Even though I increased query timeout still I am not able to fetch the result.

I tried to increase query execution timeout it failed to return records

```
<property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="3000" />

<tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- Keep SequenceService in a isolation transaction -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <!-- By default, A runtime exception will rollback transaction. -->
        <tx:method name="*" timeout="100" rollback-for="ApplicationException" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Any kind of help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Timeout occurs due to many reason. !! Can't make a suggestion unless i see the query and associated codes ..!!

Answer (score 0):

These are my thoughts about the issue here.Since i don't find any relevant codes here..

1. Due to execution of multiple queries in single fetch (issues like n+1 issue in hibernate). **Hint**:*Make sure that you set show SQL value as true in developer machine*
2. Due to irregular handling of queries in code, like if you are iterating for n number of time. The Database server will consider its as some threat and it moves to a lock state and stop execution of queries for some time period.
3. Improper handling of transaction time-out, Like if you are increasing a transaction time-out value then it will probably lock the database for a long time.

There are also other possibilities, but i cant make any suggestions unless i see the code.